# Access object in a different thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

**Setup:**

Win10 .NET 4.7.1/VS2017 .NET 4.5/ C#

**Level:**

Beginner/Intermediate/new to threading

**Objective:**

1: A selenium web automation class that is triggered by a timer class so that the web automation class can exchange data with a javascript site at specific times.

2: Should be possible to migrate solution from WebForms to .NET library (dll).

**Problem:**

Step 1. Timer class sends time event to method in Web class to login to internet site = working.

Step 2. Web automation class (WinForms/GUI) tries to retrieve data from the method that is triggered by timer class event = Exception: "Calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." (as translated from swe).

I admit I´m confused by the terminology in the area of threading that is new to me. Also, I understand some multithreading techniques are only valid for WinForms. Since my objective is to migrate the solution to a dll these are not an option for me. I´ve played around with Invoke(), but as I understand it´s limited to use in WinForms. Guidance is highly appreciated!

WEB AUTOMATION CLASS:

```
    private EdgeDriver driver;
    private SeleniumHelper helper;
    private WebAutomationTimer timer;
    private double account;

    public double Account { get => this.account; set => this.account = value; }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer = new WebAutomationTimer(02, 36, 00, 02, 38, 00);
        timer.OnLoginTime += Timer_OnLoginTime;
        timer.OnLogoutTime += Timer_OnLogoutTime;
    }

    private void Timer_OnLoginTime()
    {
        Login();
    }

    private void Timer_OnLogoutTime()
    {
        Logout();
    }

    public bool Login()
    {
        try
        {
            // working login code

    UpdateLabels();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }

    private void UpdateLabels()
    {
        // EXCEPTION !!!
        lblAccount.Text = GetAccount(); 
    // EXCEPTION !!!
    }
```

TIMER CLASS:

```
class WebAutomationTimer
{
    public event TimerEvent OnLoginTime;
    public event TimerEvent OnLogoutTime;
    //public event TimerEvent OnSecond;
    private System.Timers.Timer timer;
    private DateTime now;
    private int loginHour;
    private int loginMin;
    private int loginSec;
    private int logoutHour;
    private int logoutMin;
    private int logoutSec;

    public WebAutomationTimer(int loginHour, int loginMin, int loginSec, int logoutHour, int logoutMin, int logoutSec)
    {
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000; // 1 sec
        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Start();
        this.loginHour = loginHour;
        this.loginMin = loginMin;
        this.loginSec = loginSec;
        this.logoutHour = logoutHour;
        this.logoutMin = logoutMin;
        this.logoutSec = logoutSec;
    }

    // Each second event
    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        now = DateTime.Now;
        //OnSecond();

        //login
        if (now.Hour == loginHour && now.Minute == loginMin && now.Second == loginSec)
            OnLoginTime();

        //logout
        if (now.Hour == logoutHour && now.Minute == logoutMin && now.Second == logoutSec)
            OnLogoutTime();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: There are a lot of duplicate questions about this. You can't modify the UI from a background thread, in any OS. Before 2010, the answer was to use `BeginInvoke` to marshal the call to the UI thread. Since .NET 4.5 you can use the Progress<T> class to notify the UI thread of changes in a background thread

Comment: I´m aware this is a duplicate question out of a well initiated persons perspective. I believe I´ve red most of them. Still there are nuances in them that might be helpfull for us (me) not so well initiated. I appreciate your understanding and clearifications.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to update View's control from another `Thread` it must show you error. Because it is using by UI Thread. In this case you have to use `SynchronizationContext` class or you can send Delegate to the `App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate must be here)`;

```
SynchronizationContext _context = SynchronizationContext.Current;

private void UpdateLabels()
{
        _context.Post(x=> 
             {
                lblAccount.Text = AccountBalance.ToString();
             },null),

    //...
}
```

Alternative of SynchronizationContext :

```
private void UpdateLabels()
{
      var action = new Action(() => 
      {
              lblAccount.Text = AccountBalance.ToString();
      });

      App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);

    //...
}
```

Both of them are same.

UI thread adapted for keyboard event and mouse event.
When you `App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate)` you say to the `UI Thread` that
"execute this too".

In addition you can suppose `UI Thread` like this

```
while(!thisApplication.Ended)
{
    wait for something to appear  in message queue
    Got something : what kind of this message? 
    Keyboard/Mouse message --> fire event handler 
    User BeginInvoke message --> execute delegate
    User Invoke message --> execute delegate & post result

}
```

Comment: Is this applicable also in non GUI solutions, (a dll)? Like: (property) Account = (another thread) GetAccount()

Comment: SynchronizationContext depends on the framework you are using. Winforms uses [WindowsFormSynchronizationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext?view=netframework-4.5). And WPF use [DispatcherSynchronizationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchersynchronizationcontext?view=netframework-4.5). Only in an WPF environment it would be 'equal' to the Dispatcher. But it would be a perfect fit for migrating.

Comment: @FredrikEnqvist Both are. But you might need to add a reference to WindowsBase.dll if you are using a Dispatcher.

Comment: 1: (property) Account = (another thread) GetAccount() // no exception
2: lblAccount = (another thread) GetAccount() // throws exception
3: lblAccount = (property) Account.ToString() // throws exception

Kind of confusing, but I get the idea that once the GUI´s thread is involved there´s an exception. Would that exception persist when I try to retrieve that property from a dll where there´s no GUI involved?

Answer (score 0):

this error is beacuse of change lable text beacuse lable is in another thread you can use this code

```
 lblAccount.Invoke(new EventHandler((s, ee) => { lblAccount.Text = AccountBalance.ToString(); }));
```

Comment: Is this applicable also in non GUI solutions, (a dll)? Like: (property) Account = (Another thread) GetAccount()

Comment: Thanks Behzad! A simple line of code that worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is probably only valid in my case. OP can delete this question if it´s believed to be a duplicate.

The first objective with was an easy to develop/run/debug situation with a GUI. Setting properties causes no cross thread exception. Showing the properties in a MessageBox.Show() causes no exception either. Hence no cross thread issues to dodge in the development/GUI stage.

The second objective was to migrate to a dll, hence no need to interfere with a GUI thread.

/Thanks anyway